# Fetching multiple values serial wise, if data is repeated

Tags: excel, vba

i need help in understanding on which lookup function can i use, that fetches values from another sheet in serial order. In the attached image you would see that a product has multiple order id's. I want the lookup to fetch values in serial number(ignoring the value fetched earlier) when product name is entered twice in the lookup sheet. Is there a vba function or a formula for such search. I am a novice and help will be appriciated.

Original Sheet
[image: Original Sheet]

Lookup sheet
[image: Lookup sheet]

Comment: How about FILTER and SORTBY?

Comment: Countif(OriginalSheet!B:B,a2)
"a2" is the first "P-1" on Lookup sheet- will count number of times P-1 is in original sheet - would that help?

Answer (score 0):

We are going to need a helper column to identify available IDs: **Available Serial IDs**:

[image: sample excel file]

and here is the formula:

```
=LET(availableIds, IF(ROW(E2)=2, ISNUMBER($A$2:$A$8),
  ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$8,$F1:F$2,0))=FALSE), IF(E2="","", 
  XLOOKUP(E2,FILTER($B$2:$B$8, availableIds), 
  FILTER($A$2:$A$8, availableIds))))
```

To build a recurrence we consider two scenarios: the first Product to search and the rest of them. The first search is identified via condition: `ROW(E2)=2` but you can use a different one, for example to leave a blank row before and to check whether the previous row is empty or not. When we are on the first search, then all IDs are available, we achieve it via the following trick: `ISNUMBER($A$2:$A$8)` (I assume from the question that all serial number values are numbers).

After the first search, our `LET` variable (`avaialableIds`) now is determined as follow:

```
ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$8,$F1:F$2,0))=FALSE
```

**Note**: Once we drag-down the formula, for row 3 and 4 it looks as follow:

```
ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$8,$F2:F$2,0))=FALSE
ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$2:$A$8,$F$2:F3,0))=FALSE
```

So we look for previous available IDs for a `MATCH` in **Serial Num.** column, it  returns the row position for previous available ids. Checking for `ISNUMBER` it returns `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`. Because we need to find the Ids not previously found we compare against `FALSE`. So we are going to have `TRUE` only if the serial id was not used before.

Now we use a `XLOOKUP` function filtering the ranges using the output of `FILTER` on each case, so it ensures it will find only **Serial Num.** values that were not used before.

Finally having the **Available Serial ID** value, then to obtain the **Order Number** is straightforward:

```
=XLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$A$8,$C$2:$C$8)
```

The rest is just drag-down the formulas to the end. I hope it helps.